# How to stop jsonPayload in stackdriver from being transformed to struct format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm logging a simple json structure in **google cloud function**:

```
console.info(JSON.stringify({message: 'xxx', data: {status: 200}, status: 200}));
```

but I'm seeing an unreadable structure in stack driver below, how to stop stackdriver from transforming the log?

[image]

Comment: Does it really make a problem? Maybe it's only when you view it in web but search queries and export would ignore the nesting? Just wondering.

Comment: @Nakilon it makes the payload very hard to read :(

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147978256) reporting a similar issue were JSON strings are wrongly being ingested into the jsonPayload.

You can track the resolution of this issue in the mentioned link